# Java GUI group chat app using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I was wondering why my send button in this gui group chat doesn't print the message I want to the intend text area, everything compiles and there are no errors so I'm kind of at a loss, any help would be appreciated. This is my first post on here so please forgive any formatting errors. I have attached my code below, any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

```
    package ChatGUI;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;


 public class preDisplay extends Thread{

    String username;
    public void run() {
    JFrame preFrame = new JFrame();
    JButton enterChat = new JButton("Enter Chat");
    JTextField chooseUserName = new JTextField("Enter desired username");
    preFrame.add(chooseUserName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    chooseUserName.setBounds(15,20,250,50);

    enterChat.setBounds(80,80,120,40);  
    preFrame.add(enterChat);           
    preFrame.setSize(300,200); 
    preFrame.setLayout(null); 
    preFrame.setVisible(true);

    enterChat.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
         { 
              username = chooseUserName.getText();
              preFrame.setVisible(false);

         }
    });

}
```

}

```
   package ChatGUI;

   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
   import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
   import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
   import javax.swing.JButton;
   import javax.swing.JFrame;
   import javax.swing.JTextArea;
   import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class SendMessageUI extends Thread{

    public void run() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();//create new frame
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("send");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        textField.setBounds(15,20,250,50);

        DisplayMessages display = new DisplayMessages();
        preDisplay pre_disp = new preDisplay();

        sendButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
             {
                  display.textArea.append(pre_disp.username + ": " + " " + textField.getText() + '\n');
             }
        });

        sendButton.setBounds(100,80,80,40);//x axis, y axis, width, height  
        frame.add(sendButton);//adding button in JFrame            
        frame.setSize(300,200);//300 width and 200 height  
        frame.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers  
        frame.setVisible(true);//show frame
}
```

}

```
    package ChatGUI;



    public class DisplayMessages extends Thread{

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    public void run(){
    JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();//create new frame
    frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);//set behavior when closed
    frame2.setSize(400,300);//400 width and 300 height  
    frame2.setLayout(null);//using no layout managers  
    frame2.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame2.setVisible(true);//show frame

    textArea.setBounds(15,20,350,220);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    frame2.add(textArea);
}
```

}

```
    package ChatGUI;

    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new preDisplay());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SendMessageUI());
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new DisplayMessages());

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
}
```

}

Comment: Please, please, please go read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) - Swing is **NOT** thread safe and you shouldn't be modifying any aspect of the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. You would also do yourself a massive favour by doing some research into things like "model-view-controller"

Comment: Okay thank you I will

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the text of the wrong DisplayMessages object. You're creating a new non-displayed one and are sending the text to that one, while meanwhile the displayed one gets no text sent to it. The whole problem is one of understanding what a Java object/reference is and setting the state of the *correct* reference, not some random reference that happens to be the same type as the one of interest.

Here:

```
public class SendMessageUI extends Thread{

public void run() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();//create new frame
    JButton sendButton = new JButton("send");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    frame.add(textField, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    textField.setBounds(15,20,250,50);

    DisplayMessages display = new DisplayMessages();
```

This DisplayMessages object is not the one displayed to the user.

Instead here:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t1 = new Thread(new preDisplay());
    Thread t2 = new Thread(new SendMessageUI());
    Thread t3 = new Thread(new DisplayMessages());  // ******
```

is the one that is actually displayed.

The solution to this is to study what a Java object truly is, what a reference to an object implies, and then passing the true object of interest to where it is needed so that its state is changed when required.

There are a lot of unrelated issues present including:

- Ignoring Swing threading rules, including creating and displaying Swing GUI's and changing their state **off** of the Swing event thread. You'll want to read [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to learn how to handle Swing threading correctly
- Extending Thread rather than implementing Runnable or Callable
- Using null layouts and absolute positioning

Comment: Okay thank you for the guidance, I have just recently started java and 
between not knowing how to reference objects correctly and being unsure on the responsibilities of the initial thread, event dispatch thread and worker threads, and how exactly they function, I was at a loss.

Comment: Is there anyway you could point me in the right way of how to reference the object that is displayed? Or provide a resource that could possibly help. Referencing objects has been the main problem for me since starting java.

Comment: @KendallGarousi: truthfully I think that you've got the cart before the horse. First learn basic Java OOPs concepts, which is the main problem here. Only after doing this, learn more obscure corners of Java such as GUI coding.

Comment: Okay thank you, I often read the concepts and understand the basics pretty well but then have trouble applying and elaborating on them, probably just need to practice more. I knew about concurrency in swing but tried to find a solution that wouldn't need it based on my very limited knowledge of threads. I should know by now that I can't take shortcuts with this stuff.